# scala compiler with ant build error

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, ant, build-error

I am trying to compile the scala compiler with ant, however when i do an ant or ant build my build fails. I really can't believe I can't figure out whats wrong.

I have ant installed and have run other (smaller) things using it. Java version 1.7.

I have also got the source code form several sources, including the scala svn repository, so it really should work, and im pretty sure it should compile. Maybe environment error on my side?

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but with no luck and I can't find anything on the internet to help at all..

The fatal error I get is in the locker.comp section of cmd printout, however I get a warning just before it which I will also put down (briefly).

```
locker.lib
[mkdir] created
[javac compiling 25 source files]
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source
[javac] 1 warning
[scalafork] compiling 688 files
[property file] creating property file
[stopwarch] [locker.lib.timer blah.. sec]

locker.pre-comp:

locker.comp:
[mkdir]Created dir %path%\build\locker\classes\compiler
[scalafork] Compiling 451 files to dir
[scalafork] error: source file '3\Software' could not be found
[scala fork] one error found

BUILD FAILED
%path%\build.xml:356 java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed because 
of an internal compiler error

     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
     at scala.tools.ant.sabbus.ScalaFork.execute........
```

I have no idea what 3\Software is or where it should be..
Any help on the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have directories with spaces in their name? Try to put everything in directories that don't have spaces. Also use JDK 1.6 to compile, I am not sure if the Scala team routinely compiles with 1.7.

Comment: Do you really think I'll need to take java out of "Program Files (x86)", surely it uses the %JAVA_HOME% env variable.. I'll try it, know the scala stuff has no spaces in the name,.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on Win64 and based on the error message there is something weird about a path under `3\Software`. This in itself would suggest it is *not* the path of the JRE/JDK. So what I'm suggesting below may not help.

I would do one of the following:

1. install the 64 bits JDK on a path with no space and try again
2. use the `mklink /D` dos command to create a link to the jdk and change `ant` to run with the jdk under that virtual path.

like this (start cmd.exe as administrator):

```
mklink /D c:\util\jdk "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6"
```

The last time I compiled the compiler was a may be two months back and I was using cygwin, a recent 1.6 JDK installed on `c:\util\java\jdk1.6.0_21`.

Note that `ant` has some option that dumps lots of information about what it's trying (`-v`) I think. You can try see if it tells you more.

Comment: Huynhjl, you aren't just a pretty face! It turns out I had ant installed in a directory which was *space*3\Software*space*eng*space*methods\...   
Only saw that after I read your post.  You didn't find the exact problem but your prompting was spot on =)

Compiling now, got past the place where I was stuck

I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: That problem is fixed but I'm now getting another error.  Dont know how the source files can be buggy so again I'm confused.  I'll re-post as another question as I can't fit the log here.